# What is Senator Votto's actual relation to Nina, and motivation for having her rescued by Joe?

Tags: plot-explanation, you-were-never-really-here

In *You Were Never Really Here*, State Senator Albert Votto hires Joe to rescue Nina, who he says is his daughter, from a pedophile ring. He mentions that he has heard Joe is brutal and that he wants Joe to "hurt them" (the pedophile ring people).

However, there seem to be scenes where it is implied that Votto is one of Nina's abusers and is part of this same pedophile ring. Nina also doesn't seem to have an emotional reaction after seeing the news report on the TV about Senator Votto's death. It seems that Senator Votto might not be Nina's father at all.

[image: Senator Votto with Nina] [image: Senator Votto with Nina]

Votto, shown with Governor Williams:
[image: Votto with Governor Williams] [image: Votto with Governor Williams]

If Votto is involved with the pedophile ring, why would he have Nina rescued? If he is not involved, what do these scenes imply?

Answer (score 2):

> If he is not involved, what do these scenes imply?

These scenes imply that Votto is involved in one way or another for sure. Also I would like to point out that  the scenes were shown through Joe's eyes, as if we are are observing his thought process. so any conclusion we come to will be from his perspective. The movie does not point out saying this is this and this is that.

> **It seems that Senator Votto might not be Nina's father at all.**

At one point in the [script](https://www.scriptslug.com/script/you-were-never-really-here-2017), it is said that:

> He stands and grasps a clear plastic file and places it in
> front of Joe.
> VOTTO (CONT’D):
> I got a text message this
> morning. Anonymous.
> Joe reads the text as Votto paces.
> VOTTO (CONT’D):
> (by heart)
> ‘Your daughter is at 544 West
> 38th street I couldn’t live
> with myself if I didn’t let you
> know’....

Also,

> ...Another photograph - formally posed, the girl wears a white
> party dress as Votto holds her in an embrace, their eyes both
> closed, his chin resting on the crown of her head.
> Joe selects the earlier selfie of the girl AND A FAMILY
> PORTRAIT - NINA between Her Mother and Father...

A lot these were not shown in the movie, though we can see a photograph of a man embracing a girl on the table. From this we can *assume* that the senator was not lying about the girl being his daughter, the movie tells us nothing more than that.

> **Nina also doesn't seem to have an emotional reaction after seeing the news report on the TV about Senator Votto's death.**

As you have said, Votto is inivolved and going back to him would make Nina his victim again,that's why Nina is so indifferent to her father's death.

> **If Votto is involved with the pedophile ring, why would he have Nina rescued?**

Votto might be directly involved with the ring **or** might have taken the advantage of his knowledge of the governor's secret trade. He might have forced his daughter to go to the governor to rise in political power, which might be the reason behind Nina's running away from home. Earlier she was found by the local police, but this time they probably couldn't find her and Votto might have freaked out about his career. Nina can defame her or he can defame the governor if he can find Nina. All these are speculations. At the end of the day, without her Votto has no upper hand to the governor. This is why he was so eager to find Nina.